# Automatically update TOC

Tags: asp.net, automation, ms-word, openxml

I'm using OpenXML on a asp.net website to create a Word document from a template and adding additional sections to the template from other templates via an `altChunk` as well as adding HTML fragments (also as `altChunk`) and images. Everything is working fine except that my template has a table of contents (TOC) and to update it with both the correct page numbers and the correct headings (for the added sections), the end user has to select the TOC and update it (by hitting F9, or clicking update field from the context menu). Even then they still have to choose between updating just page numbers or updating the whole table (confusing for the end user).

I'd really like to avoid this step because I'd like the document to be ready to go and not look like it was autogenerated on the backend.

I tried adding a `UpdateOnFieldsOpen` to the document settings, but that only causes a confusing (to the end user) nag screen when they open the document.

I thought about maybe trying to manually update the TOC in OpenXML by estimating the length (in pages) of each section I add (they should probably be fairly constant +/- a page) to give at least a fairly accurate TOC when the user first opens the doc, but that doesn't seem very robust.

Word automation would potentially fix this, but it's not recommended for server-side.

Are there any better solutions for this? It seems silly that I can arbitrarily insert chunks of other documents and HTML without any complaint, but updating the TOC is a major security concern!

Answer (score 1):

As you've no doubt become aware, this issue with updating a TOC automatically is a common complaint.

In the Java world, the docx4j enterprise (ie commercial) edition can solve it [disclosure: my company's], by generating the entire TOC independent of Word.

By the way, the docx4j community edition can also convert XHTML altChunk to native/raw WordML, which is an important first step for getting the TOC right.  You can use it in a .NET environment; see http://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j-ImportXHTML.NET/3.0.1

A left-field solution might be to invoke LibreOffice (eg via JODConverter); it'll update a TOC automatically without prompting.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jason. I was wondering if ODF would be easier, but I hadn't thought of just using LibreOffice with a docx file instead. I'll look into that. Don't know if there's a version of Open/LibreOffice that will run headless of a server...

Comment: Hmmm...It seems LibreOffice Writer mangles my layout and doesn't process the docx altChunks.

Comment: Hi Jason, my company has docx4j enterprise license.  Do you have example code of how to do this?  That is, generating the entire TOC of independent of Word so that user doesn't have to manually update the field.

Comment: These days that code is now part of docx4j itself; see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/TocUpdateDemo.java Note that for best results you ought to install your own instance of our commercial PDF Converter.

Comment: That was for updating an existing ToC;  for adding a new ToC, see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/TocAdd.java

Comment: As of 2020, to do it using docx4j, put Apache FOP on your class path, or for greater accuracy, use docx4j's documents4j integration with https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-resources/src/main/resources/documents4j_word_convert.vbs (which requires Microsoft Word)